# Reuse class / no references

Tags: c#, code-reuse

Task: reuse C# code in different projects but without project referencing (don’t want extra dll/references just because of a small utility class).
There’re 4 projects, one of them contains utility class which is currently source-code-linked by other 3 projects.
Problem: once one of the projects starts referencing one of others (for some other needs), the compiler starts complaining (obviously) that there’s the same class (with the same namespace) in these projects.

Are there any solutions other than to move the class to separate project or to make 4 copies of the class for each project and maintain them separately?

I wonder is there a way to source link files so that the class inside a file gets project-specific unique namespace…

Comment: I strongly suggest to reference the project. If you really can't, use a different namespace.

Comment: Why do you not want to use project references?  Having multiple re-usable components is exactly what you're trying to achieve, and exactly what DLLs are for.

Comment: @David: there're several projects (which are part of the same product - they all are installed on the same box) that need this utility class. These projects live in different "environments" - some of them have their dependencies locally in the same folder, some of them access GAC, some of them don't use GAC and implement their own dll loading mechanism. Putting this class into a separate project will create another problem - how to make sure the dll is accessible to all projects.

Comment: Also there are other small utility classes which can't be put into one utility assembly together - some of them reference other things like IIS, visual studio, ... - so if I needed this utility dll just for some simple utility which doesn't have references I'd still need to reference IIS and other stuff. So If I start putting all utilities in separate projects I'd create lots of small dlls which doesn't make sense for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wonder is there a way to source link files so that the class inside a file gets project-specific unique namespace…

Well you *could* use preprocessor directives:

```
#if PROJECT_FOO
namespace Foo
#elif PROJECT_BAR
namespace Bar
#elif PROJECT_BAZ
namespace Baz
#endif
```

... and then link the file into each project, defining appropriate symbols in the project properties.

But I would *thoroughly* recommend against it. It's horrible, and it's certainly not how C# was designed to be written.

Just break it out into a separate project - you're bound to find you want more and more code like this anyway.

Comment: I like this answer because it's creative one, even though I don't think I'll follow this preprocessor approach... But my question was about creative solutions, not right ones :) Thanks!

Comment: @Max: Well it's "right" in that it's "correct" - it will do what you asked. But I don't think you should do it anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

To the question:

*"Are there any solutions other than to move the class to separate project or to make 4 copies of the class for each project and maintain them separately?"*

The short answer is: **no, there isn't**. Or at least, there is no *elegant* way of doing that.

The right way is indeed to make it part of a referenced project. But you don't have to make a project that will contain JUST that utility class! Instead, make it a project holding multiple simple utilities with as little dependencies as possible and share it across your solutions. Much easier and cleaner this way.

Comment: @downvoter, if you feel this answer isn't appropriate, please explain why. Thanks.